# Django order by queryset from a method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to order by `entry_count` but it seems (from the django error) I can only order by name and status. How can I order by `entry_count` in this example? Thanks

```
Category.objects.filter(status='Published').order_by('-entry_count')
```

Model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Entry Categories.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text="Title of Category")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default="Draft", )
    @property
    def entry_count(self):
        return Entry.objects.filter(category=self.id).count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Category.objects.annotate(
    entry_count=Count('entry_set')
).order_by('-entry_count')
```

Like this, you'll get all the counts in one query and all the category objects will have `entry_count`, so you can remove the `@property` from the model.